# How to 'add caused_By in ComboBox' in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I have created a database. In the Database, I have created a table called "Diseases". In Table, there is some column Name. I want to display 'bacteria, virus and protozoa' in a comboBox in visual.

```
create table Diseases
( DiseasesID int primary key identity,
  Disease_Name varchar(80),
  Caused_by varchar(80) check(caused_by IN('bacteria','virus','protozoa')),
  PatientID int
  foreign key (patientID) references patient
);
```

Comment: You want display value of caused_by column to  the combobox ?? not clear ??

Answer (score 0):

There's not a way that I know of to reference the possible values of an `IN` constraint in a query. Rather than hard-coding the possible values into a constraint, create a "lookup table" and create a foreign key from `Diseases` to the lookup table. Then you can use the lookup table as the source for the combo box.